# Laravel Passport Authorization Code Grant

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport, laravel-breeze

I have a rough idea on implementing Authorization Code Grant.

I understand the general flow is

a. Application/Client requests Auth code from resource server by passing the client-id,scope,redirect_uri

b. Resource server prompts user to login with their credentials and authorize, then redirects back to callback url which is in the client

c. Then client uses auth code to request for access token.

d. if everything went well, resource server returns the access token and refresh token

e. Client stores the access token and refresh token in http cookie

However , in step b , I would like user to Login then redirect to an OTP page **before redirecting them back to the callback url which is in the client**

**My idea**

a. Make user to login

b. Create an access token with a scope of request_otp_payment and a route with middleware of auth:api and scope of request_otp_payment , so that only logged in users and users with tokens that has scope of request_otp_payment  can access this route.

c. Once user logs in, the api returns a token and redirect them to the otp page

d. Once user is redirected and keys in the otp I would revoke this token.

**The problem**

I am stuck with csrf token mismatch

[image]

**My code**

```
//Web.php
Route::get('/otp', [AuthController::class, 'otpPage'])->name('requireotp')->middleware(['auth', 'scope:request_otp_payment']);

Route::middleware('guest')->group(function () {
    Route::get('login',  [AuthController::class, 'create'])->name('login');
    Route::post('login',  [AuthController::class, 'store'])->name('login.store');
});

//AuthController.php
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function create(Request $request): Response
    {
        return Inertia::render('Passport/Login', [
            'canResetPassword' => Route::has('password.request'),
            'status' => session('status'),
        ]);
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $user = null;
        $token = null;
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6',
        ]);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            $errors = $validator->errors();
            return response(['errors' => $errors], 422);
        }
        $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();
        if ($user) {
            if (Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
                $token = $user->createToken('otp Token', ['request_otp_payment'])->accessToken;
                $response = ['token' => $token];
                return response($response, 200);
            } else {
                return throw ValidationException::withMessages([
                    'email' => [trans('auth.failed')],
                ]);
            }
        } else {
            return throw ValidationException::withMessages([
                'email' => [trans('auth.failed')],
            ]);
        }
    }
    
    public function otpPage(Request $request)
    {
        $intended_route = $request->session()->get('url')['intended'];
        $state = $request->session()->pull('state');
        return Inertia::render('Passport/Otp', [
            'intendedRoute' =>  $intended_route,
            'state' => $state
        ]);
    }
}

//Login.jsx 

    const submit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("submitting to Passport Post Route...");
        //  post(route("login.store"));
        try {
            const response = await axios.post(route("login.store"), {
                email: data.email,
                password: data.password,
            });
            const { token } = response?.data;
            if (token) {
                console.log("hrere");
                return Inertia.visit("/otp"); //once, i get the token, i redirect them to the otp page
            }
        } catch (error) {
            const errorResponse = error?.response?.data?.errors;
            //returns array of errors
            if (errorResponse) {
                setError({
                    email: errorResponse.email ? email[0] : null,
                    password: errorResponse.password ? password[0] : null,
                });
            }
        }
    };
```

This is my general idea on the work flow, I am not sure, if this is the correct approach, please feel free to correct me. Thank you very much